# outputting an adjacency list from sets of neighbors in an undirected graph

Tags: python, tree, breadth-first-search, adjacency-list

Say we have the following undirected graph:

```
        0
       /  \
      1    2
            \
             3 
      4
```

I'm writing a function that takes in as input a representation of the graph above that looks like the following:

`[{1, 2}, set(), {3}, set()]`

This is a list of sets where each set index represents a node, and every element in the set represents the node's children. It should take this list, and output a text file that looks like the following:

```
   0
   0,3
   2 
   -
```

This is an adjacency list where each line number (not written) represents the node, and each element in-line is the node's neighbors. Any vertex with no neighbor (like 4) should have a ‘-’ on its line.

I'm struggling with writing a function that writes the node's parent in front as well. Can anyone think of a pythonic way to do that?

What I have so far is not doing it's job! n, here, is the length of T:

```
def processT(T,n):
    string = ""
    for i in range(n):
        elem = str(T[i])
        if elem != "set()":
            string += elem.strip("{}").replace(" ","") + "\n"
        else:
            string += "-\n"
    file1 = open("output.txt", "w")
    file1.write(string)
    file1.close()
```

Any ideas would be very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What about (I just print instead of writing to a file)

```
def set_to_str(s):
    if len(s) == 0:
        return "-"
    else:
        return ",".join(map(str, s))

T = [{1, 2}, set(), {3}, set()]
for i, s in zip(range(len(T)), T):
    set_str = set_to_str(s)
    print("{} {}".format(i, set_str))
```

Comment: A real (nearly unreadable) pythonic way: Just replace the for loop with 

    `"\n".join([f"{i} {set_to_str(s)}" for (i,s) in zip(range(len(T)), T)])`

Note: this works only for Python 3.6 or later.

Comment: As a general rule: do not create a string from already well-represented data (sets or lists) and process that string. It is usually alot simpler to just work with list comprehension, `map()`, and `str.join()`.

Comment: The main complication I had with this code is that I shouldn't write the line number. For example, on a big adjacency list, I got: 
`
0 1,2
1 3,4
2 6,7
3 -
4 5
5 -
6 -
7 -
`
when it should be
`1,2
0,3,4
0,6,7
1
1,5
4
2
2
`

Comment: Then omit `{i}` in the f string expression.

Comment: But, if for example, I have 2 nodes: 0 -- 1 and they're connected to each other, this would output `1` then `-` when it should be `1` and `0`. It's an undirected graph, we must list the parent node as a neighbor